# Proving that $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ subgroup of $G$ with $\operatorname{ord}(H)=k$

> I need to prove that $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$

$\color{grey}{(gHg^{-1}=\{ghg^{-1}\mid g\in G, h\in H\})}$

**My attempt:**

Let $a,b \in H$

$1)  $  To check that $(gag^{-1})^{-1}\in G$

$2)$  $(gag^{-1})\cdot (gbg^{-1}) \in G$

---

$1) $$  (gag^{-1})^{-1}=g^{-1^{-1}}a^{-1}g^{-1}=ga^{-1}g^{-1}$

$2)$ $ ga(g^{-1}g)bg^{-1}=g(ab)g^{-1}$

> I'm stuck at this point, Is it correct so far? is there other methods to solve this? any hints please?

Comment: You seem to understand it. Perhaps you should be more explicit in your 'proof'. There are a lot of details needed to be clear.

Comment: @Arthur I fixed it $a,b \in H$

Comment: You conclude the last point by saying that $ab\in H$ since $H$ is supposed to be a (sub)group. To answer the question faster, you can just show that for all $x,y \in gHg^{-1}$, you have $xy^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: I am sure you meant : Let $a,b \in H$, to check 1) and 2)

$$ 1)  \ (gag^{-1})^{-1}\in \color{red}{gHg^{-1}} \\ 

2) \ (gag^{-1})\cdot (gbg^{-1}) \in \color{red}{gHg^{-1}}$$ Since that is what your attempt proves. Now having this you only need to check that $e\in gHg^{-1}$ to conclude that indeed you have a subgroup !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're way sounds good. I'm just gonna do it the standard way

$gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G \Longleftrightarrow $
$$$$
$gHg^{-1}$ Nonempty ie
$$gHg^{-1}\neq \emptyset
$$
and (the closure inverse condition)
$$\forall x,y \in gHg^{-1} , \quad xy^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}
$$

To show $gHg^{-1}$ nonempty, we consider the fact that $H \leq G \Longrightarrow e \in H$
but $$e = geg^{-1} $$ so this means
$$e=geg^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}$$

So the identity is in $gHg^{-1}$ meaning $$gHg^{-1}\neq \emptyset
$$ as needed.

Now the second part. Let
$$x=gag^{-1}, y=gbg^{-1}: x,y \in gHg^{-1}
$$
Then consider 
$$xy^{-1}=gag^{-1} \circ \left( gbg^{-1} \right)^{-1}
$$

where $a,b \in H$. Since $H$ has inverses, we find,
$$\Longrightarrow xy^{-1}=gag^{-1} \circ \left( g^{-1} \right)^{-1} bg^{-1}
$$

$$\Longrightarrow xy^{-1}=ga\circ e \circ bg^{-1}
$$

$$ \Longrightarrow xy^{-1}=g(ab)g^{-1}
$$

Now by closure and inverses of $H$, we have that $ab \in H$

Thus overall, we have shown $xy^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: I am sorry, but why is not $gag^{-1}\circ (g^{-1})^{-1}b^{-1}g^{-1}$?

Comment: Ah well spotted! Typo :)

Answer (score 3):

If you can use homomorphisms, then this is clear because $gHg^{-1}$ is the image of $H$ under the homomorphism $G \to G$ given by $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

*The proof that I am familiar with* :

We first note that as $ H \leq G$, we have that $e \in H$. Then resultantly $geg^{-1} \in H$ which implies that H is non-empty.

Then we let $gh_{a}g^{-1},gh_{b}g^{-1},gh_{c}g^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}$.
Now 
$$ 
gh_{a}g^{-1}gh_{b}g^{-1} = gh_{a}h_{b}g^{-1}
$$
which is in $gHg^{-1}$ as $H$ is closed. Now using the fact that $H$ is a subgroup of G and contains inverses, 
\begin{align*} 
(gh_{c}g^{-1})^{-1} &= (g^{-1})^{-1}h_{c}^{-1}g^{-1} \\
&= gh_{c}^{-1}g^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}
\end{align*}

We have thus shown that $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$.